# How can I replace a word in a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, methods, replace, streamreader

I am trying to open a .txt file, search for one word and replace it with another everywhere it appears. I can do this but not with .txt file only with string's that I wrote myself in the `.cs` file.Here is the method I have so far:

```
public void EditorialControl(string fileName, string word, string replacement)
    {            
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(directory + fileName))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {                   
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                list.Add(line);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
     }
```

When I call the method in the `Main()`, it should take the parameters `word` and replace it with a replacement word of my choice.

Can you guys help me with the code to replace a word in the method?

Comment: I would also like to add that I cant use other Classes because it is not part of my assignment. The only one I have learn about is List, Console, String and recently StreamReader and StreamWriter so please try and keep your answers simple but thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: earlier today I made a different program but the code to replace a word was like this " string correction = sentence.Replace("speal", "spell");"The thing with this one is that it didnt need to read from a text file. Can you guys think of a way similar to this that I can use for the program I am doing now? thanks :)

Comment: Are you wanting to write the new text into a different file or the same file?

Comment: no I dont need to write it into a new file or different file, I just need the words that are being changed to be displayed in the cmd along with the rest of the text in the text file

Comment: i guess all of the answers here have solved your problem..y not accept one of them if that has solved your problem..it's very **rude** that you dont `acknowledge` others help....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is way simpler than you might think:

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, File.ReadAllText(fileName).Replace(word1, word2));
```

And that's it!

Comment: Ah I should have stated that I tried a code similar like that earlier and it worked but I am trying to do this for an assignment and well I cant things like "File." because I havent learnt about it yet. But thank you for your help. i just need to find a way for the word variable to be set as a word in the text file so I can replace it with the replacement variable

Comment: this would also replace a word which is part of another word..Ex.if u want to replace a `word` **some** it would `replace` **somewhere** which is not a `word`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex`

```
string target=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(directory + fileName);
Regex.Replace(target,@"\b"+word+@"\b",replacement);
```

Comment: Why would you introduce the complexity of regular expressions for which there is a stock C# method (`.Replace`)?

Comment: [What are you talking about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)?

Comment: @KirkWoll Ex.. if u want to replace a **word** `some` it would replace `somewhere` which is not a **word**

Comment: Now you are inventing requirements. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll OP specifically asks to replace a `word`!A `word` is a string that is separated by `space`..Now how am I inventing the requirements

Comment: earlier today I made a different program but the code to replace a word was like this " string correction = sentence.Replace("speal", "spell");"The thing with this one is that it didnt need to read from a text file. Can you guys think of a way similar to this that I can use for the program I am doing now? thanks :)

Comment: +1. I'm with Some1.Kill.The.DJ on "word" thingie. Also implementing proper word detection would be nice touch for most basic assignmet on File operations :)

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - `somewhere` certainly is a word.  Ever hear the song "Somewhere Over The Rainbow"?